# Fighting defensively penalty (penalty on attack rolls, damage rolls or both?)

Tags: pathfinder-1e, combat

Greetings fellow adventures!

A little query in regards to [fight defensively](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Fighting-Defensively-as-a-Standard-Action)

> You can choose to fight defensively when attacking. If you do so, you
>   take a –4 penalty on all attacks in a round to gain a +2 to AC until
>   the start of your next turn.

Is that a -4 to the attack roll, damage roll or both?

I noticed that in description of [Shooting or Throwing into a Melee](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Shooting-or-Throwing-into-a-Melee) the attack roll specifically is mentioned

> If you shoot or throw a ranged weapon at a target engaged in melee
>   with a friendly character, you take a –4 penalty on your attack roll.
>   Two characters are engaged in melee if they are enemies of each other
>   and either threatens the other. (An unconscious or otherwise
>   immobilized character is not considered engaged unless he is actually
>   being attacked.)

This leads me to believe that as one roll is not specifically mentioned it would be for both.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

'Attacks' or 'attack roll' both refer to the attack roll only, not damage. If damage should be included, it is explicitly mentioned.

So **fighting defensively gives a -4 penalty to attack rolls only. Damage is unchanged**.

If you look at it thematically, it would make sense for the character's swing to be less precise while fighting defensively (and thus give a penalty on the attack roll, resulting in a higher chance of miss). IF he/she would hit, though, the damage his/her weapon would do should still be the same (i.e same weapon, same force behind the swing, etc)